# Dequeue Custom TableViewCell not working properly

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

in my project I set up I custom tableViewCell in a TableViewController.
In my custom cell I have set a label indicating a category, a label indicating the sum for the current category (eg. for category "holidays" the sum is 300$) and an ImageView that should indicate the amount respect to the total of every category.. this is an example of how it should look like ->

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWxWS.png)

The problem is that I set the constraints for my imageView programmatically and when I scroll down and then up again the constraints doesn't work properly.
This is the code inside cellForRowAtIndex

```
let quantity: [Double] = [100, 60, 40, 15, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
let categories: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "L", "M"]
let total: Double = 230

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

    cell.labelCategory.text = "Category \(categories[indexPath.row])"
    cell.labelQuantity.text = "Quantity: \(quantities[indexPath.row])"

    let width = cell.frame.width

    let percentageImageView: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.image = UIImage(named: "percentage")
        view.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: width, height: 20))
        return view
    }()

    cell.addSubview(percentageImageView)

    let percentage = (quantity[indexPath.row] / total)


    percentageImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    percentageImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.labelCategory.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    percentageImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    percentageImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width * CGFloat(percentage)).isActive = true

    return cell
}
```

The problem is that after the scrolling some cells show the percentageImageView with wrong widths, for example in the photo below categories "M" and "L" shouldn't have the imageView because the width is 0.0.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as3gB.png)

Comment: Cells get reused so you end up adding multiple image views to each cell. Put the code to create, add, and setup the image view inside the custom cell class, not in `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: FYI - using an image isn't necessary. Create a simple view with desired background color. Then size the view to the needs size.

Comment: I did put my UIView in the cell class and tried to change only the width in the cellForRowAt but it doesn't work. In this case when I scroll down the views of the first cells disappear. Is there a way to not dequeue cells?

Answer (score -2):

I solved my problem creating an array of custom UITableViewCell and loading cells from the array.

```
var arrayOfCells: [MyTableViewCells] = []

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if arrayOfCells.count == quantity.count {
        return arrayOfCells[indexPath.row]!
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        cell.labelCategory.text = "Category \(categories[indexPath.row])"
        cell.labelQuantity.text = "Quantity: \(quantities[indexPath.row])"

        let width = cell.frame.width

        let percentageImageView: UIImageView = {
           let view = UIImageView()
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.image = UIImage(named: "percentage")
            view.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: width, height: 20))
            return view
        }()

        cell.addSubview(percentageImageView)

        let percentage = (quantity[indexPath.row] / total)


        percentageImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        percentageImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.labelCategory.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        percentageImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
        percentageImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width * CGFloat(percentage)).isActive = true

        arrayOfCells.append(cell)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Then in the viewWillAppear I simply empty the array of cells and reload the tableView.

Don't know if it is a good method to use but seems to work.

Comment: That's a very bad solution. A better one is: 1) Design the image view in the cell including the autolayout constraints 2) Create an `IBOutlet` for the `width` constraint and connect it. 3) Reuse the cell and set the constant of the constraint accordingly.

Comment: ... or use a simple `UIView` (full width) and draw the colored rectangle with variable width.

Comment: *isWorking* != *isEfficient* necessarily

Comment: Why should the IBOutlet constraint work different than setting the widthAnchor like I did first?

Comment: Dequeueing cells is an approved and memory and performance optimized pattern. Don't fight the framework.

Comment: Yes I perfectly know that is more efficient dequeuing cells. In my case there should not be more than 20 cells so I don't think this solution will cause inefficiencies. The fact is that dequeuing cells in my case, create a mess with constraints of my UIView. And I'm asking why creating an IBOutlet for the constraints should work...